# Проблема работы remote: true при прикреплении картинки

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть код всплывашки

```
<div class="modal">
    <div id="modal-6">
    <%#= render @p::ErrorReport %>
        <div class="box_m box_m_middle" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="report_error">
                    <div class="name">Сообщить об ошибке</div>
                    <div class="arcticmodal-close close"></div>
                    <p class="info_block">Форма отправки ошибок</p>
                    <div class="error_explanation">Email имеет неверное значение</div>
                    <div class="message_send">Сообщение отправлено</div>
                    <p class="thanks">Благодарим Вас за участие!</p>
                    <div class="form">
                        <%= form_for @image, url: error_create_url, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="box1 blocks">
                                <%= f.label :Имя, class: "label" %>
                                <%= f.text_field :user, class:"int int2", placeholder: "для обратной связи с вами" %>
                            </div><!--
                    /--><div class="box2 blocks">
                                <%= f.label :Почта, class: "label" %>
                                <%= f.text_field :email, class:"int int2", placeholder: "для обратной связи с вами" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <%= f.label :Сообщение, class: "label" %>
                            <%= f.text_area :message, class:"int int2", placeholder: "изложите суть возникшие  у вас проблемы" %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rows">
                            <div class="box1 blocks">
                                <div class="file">
                                    <!-- <div>Прикрепить файл</div> -->
                                    <i class="i i_paper_clip"></i>
                                    <%= f.file_field :file , class: 'choose_file' %>
                                    <img id="error_report_image">
                                </div>
                            </div><!--
                    /--><div class="box2 blocks">
                                <%= f.submit "Отправить", class: 'btn btn_middle btn_radius5' %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть JS'ка, которая обрабатывает Ajax полученный из формы благодаря remote: true

```
function error_report_init(){
 var modal6 = $('#modal-6')
 var incorrect_mail = $('.error_explanation')
  $('body').on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
    if (status == 'ok') {
      incorrect_mail.hide()
      modal6.find('.form').hide()
      modal6.find('.report_error .message_send').show()
      modal6.find('.report_error .thanks').show()
      modal6.find('.info_block').hide()
      modal6.find('.name').hide()
    } else {
      incorrect_mail.show()
    }
  })
  $('body').on('ajax:error', function(data, status, xhr) {
  })
}
```

Есть так же контролер, в котором все это чудо обрабатывается

```
class Desktop::Vision::ErrorController < CatalogController
  domain_layout 'page_screen'

  def form
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

      if @image.save
        ::Mailer::FromSite.error_report(@image).deliver_later
        # Mailer::FromSite.error_report_alias(@image).deliver_later
         render_status 'ok'
      else
         render_status @image.errors.full_messages
      end
  end

    def reported
    end

    private

    def image_params
        params.require(:image).permit(:user, :email, :message, :file)
    end

  def render_status status
    render plain: status
    return
  end
end
```

При отправке сообщения об ошибке без картинки, mailCather перехватывает сообщение так же выводится всплывашка,"Сообщение отправлено".Если же я прикреплю картинку, rails'а ведет себя крайне странно, и не выводит эту самую же всплывашку, а просто url из контролера либо рендерит "ok" либо "@image.errors.full_messages"(ошибку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вдруг, вы используете remote:true, и хотите, чтобы Ajax работал корректно при отправке файлов на сервер, проверяйте установлен ли гем `rails-ujs`. После установки все работает, проблему решил